# Aftermarket Exhaust

Tags: volvo, exhaust

I have a Volvo c30 D5(2007) and my exhaust has started to rot through from the inside, I obtained several quotes from various part providers and they all said an after market exhaust would be allot cheaper than an OEM one as they don't really make them anymore.

The only problem is the after market exhaust is for the T5 model and they can't guarantee it will fit on the D5, does anyone know if there is a difference between the D5 and the T5 exhaust system ?

The aftermarket exhaust in question is a Jetex system

Comment: I've spoken to powerflow previously and unfortunately they where abit too pricey, they wanted about £800 excluding VAT for a catback system

Comment: Not far off what my mate paid for his system... Factor in its lifetime.

Comment: There will be differences between the T5 and D5 exhausts: at least the catalaytic converter(s) will be different (diesel vs. petrol).

Comment: @Hobbes I can't seem to reply to your comment or edit my question but as it's a catback system the exhaust connects from the downpipe so the cat/dpf shouldn't make a difference

Comment: It looks like you've created 2 different user accounts with the same name.

Comment: @scriptss - Yes, the original question is on an unregistered account, while the second one is registered.

Comment: This is  becoming parts shopping assistance, but try local motor factors, eurocarparts, GSF, etc. A custom stainless one will be very pricey. Eurocarparts is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

There is another possibility : in the UK there are companies that will make you a stainless exhaust from scratch - don't have a name to hand, but a friend had his subaru done and it is much better.
Here's one, no affiliation, just one that came up after a search:
www.powerflowexhausts.co.uk